# How to get most recent modified date pdf file and display on VB from?

Tags: vb.net

i'm trying to get vb to read the most recent modified pdf file in a specific folder and display the pdf file on my vb form. I only able to create a simple pdf display on my vb form and i'm stuck at this. Can anyone help?

Unable to find solution to my problem.

```
    Dim testFile As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fullPath As String

    testFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\Users\example.pdf")
    folderPath = testFile.DirectoryName
    fileName = testFile.Name
    fullPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(folderPath, fileName)
    AxAcroPDF1.src = fullPath
```

my vb form should display the PDF based on the most recent modified file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IO.DirectoryInfo class to get every IO.FileInfo in a directory while specifically targeting PDF files, then use LINQ to order them by their LastWriteTime, and then get the last file from the collection:

```
Dim folder As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo("my folder path here")
Dim lastModifiedPdf As IO.FileInfo = folder.GetFiles("*.pdf").OrderBy(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime).LastOrDefault()

If lastModifiedPdf IsNot Nothing Then
    '....
End If
```

Comment: Thanks @David . Just quick question. Now that i'm displaying PDF in my VB form. How do i display PDF or image file outside of VB form?

Comment: I would suggest opening a separate thread, but generally if you just want to open a file using the default application use the Process.Start method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You need to call two sets of functions to achieve this.

A. [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8) - this will list all the files in a directory, and it has options to provide a search pattern and also look in sub-folders.

B. [File.GetLastWriteTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getlastwritetime?view=netframework-4.8) - this will return the last modified time of the file you pass to it.

You can put these functions together like:

```
Private Function GetLatestModifiedFileName(searchFolder As String) As String
    Dim retVal = "<empty>"

    Dim filesInDirectory() = Directory.GetFiles(searchFolder)

    Dim latestModifiedtime As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue

    For Each fileInDirectory As String In filesInDirectory
        Dim currentFileModifiedTime As DateTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileInDirectory)

        If (currentFileModifiedTime > latestModifiedtime) Then
            retVal = fileInDirectory
            latestModifiedtime = currentFileModifiedTime
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print("File: '{0}' was last modified on: '{1}'", retVal, latestModifiedtime)

    Return retVal
End Function
```

and ultimately call this function using:

```
Dim lastModifiedFileName = GetLatestModifiedFileName("D:\Documents\")
```

The variable `lastModifiedFileName` will contain the full path to the file that has the latest modified date/time.